# Search in serialized array

Tags: php, joomla

I want to do search query in serialized array that is stored in my database. Data look like this:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:16:"2013-03-24 15:00";i:1;s:16:"2013-03-24 11:00";i:2;s:16:"2013-03-17 15:00";i:3;s:16:"2013-03-17 11:00";}
```

Field name is dates. I want to search dates like '2013-03-24' but no success.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't use unserialize the array? Wouldn't that be easier?

Comment: but how can i do as i need this values from database. this is my query where i want to select data where dates like '$start_date'

Comment: SELECT t1.*,t1.title as eventname,t1.desc as description,t2.* FROM #__icagenda_events t1 INNER JOIN #__icagenda_category t2 ON t1.catid = t2.id where t1.catid='".$rowcat->id."' and t1.state='1' and t1.dates like '$start_date%' order by t1.next asc

Comment: http://php.net/unserialize

Comment: I think unserializing could lead to recursive search, if there are arrays in arrays or objects, but dates are what the author needs. Maybe he should try regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Do not store serialized arrays in database.

This is the only answer to your question.
Create a table to hold all that data you stored in a serialized form, and then store each value in a distinct cell.

Then you will be able to make a regular sql query like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date1 = '2013-03-24 15:00'
```